# How to hide generated packages in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

i am using android studio

```
Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Canary 2
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2211.8571212, built on May 11, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

and would like to hide the following generated packages which are currently visible when i employ the Android view
[image]

Comment: I think you have to change to view type from project to android type

Comment: where do i change view type?

Comment: like  [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XxHxAOBuP0K9-PEw2062VRucrZomrhP0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am in Android view and can still see those generated packages

Comment: Do you change the view type to Android ??

Comment: yes, the view type is android

Answer (score 2):

You can just "right click the directory -> Mark Directory as -> Excluded"

If you want to "Not Excluded" the directory, just find the directory and do the same action above.

For your example path:
/{projectName}/app/build/generated/source/kapt/{Variant}/